# Calling a method from a different controller in a scope in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Lets say that I have a angular module that has 2 controllers: display based and http based (uses http data using a service).

In my html file, I have a div:

```
<div ng-controller="HttpController">
    <input ng-model="data" type="text" placeholder="Enter data"/>
    <button ng-click="response(data)">Enter data</button>
</div>
```

The response(data) is making the API call.

I also want the click event to call a method from the DisplayController so that I could display a view. Is it possible for me to bundle another controller inside this div, or should I make this into one controller?

Comment: You need to be more specific the question you are asking, give a better code example that way it would be easier to assess, for example your html file and the corresponding js file or files.

Comment: I asked a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942678/load-jsonp-into-multiple-anglarjs-controllers recently, you need to use a factory or service to share data between controllers

Answer (score 0):

The best way to communicate between controllers is to reference the same serviceObject in both the controllers so if the serviceObject updates state, then the other controller knows about it.

```
function HttpController($scope, serviceObject) {}
function DisplayController ($scope, serviceObject) {}
```